# Rinkeby/Infura Block Gas Limit Issues

Tags: json-rpc, infura, gas-limit, rinkeby, ethers.js

I am trying to deploy a contract with a gasLimit of around 8,000,000 on the Rinkeby testnet using an Infura provider. Basically something like this:

```
await MyContract.deploy({ gasLimit: 8000000 });
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":58,\"error\":
{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"exceeds block gas limit\"}}", error={"code":-32000}, 
requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendRawTransaction\",\"params\": ......
```

from Infura. Looking at the latest Rinkeby blocks, the gasLimit seems to be around 30,000,000:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/blocks

What gives? Is the gas limit actually lower than 30 million? Does Infura have some set value that it thinks is the correct gas limit and is throwing an error when I pass it? I'm really not sure what is going on here. Any help is greatly appreciated.